# Why can't I change a string by index when it is declared by pointer notation?

Tags: c

for example:

```
char stringer[]="hello";
stringer[2]='A';
```

The above works to change `'l'` to `'A'`. But if I do the following:

```
char *stringer="hello";
stringer[2]='A';
```

This doesn't work, is there a reason for this?

Comment: Literal strings are really *non-modifiable* arrays of characters. With `char *stringer="hello";` you make `stringer` point to the first character of such an array. Attempting to modify its contents leads to *undefined behavior*. That's why you should always use `const char *` when pointing to literal strings. This should have been taught by any decent book, tutorial or class.

Comment: Also note that you *can* modify strings when using pointer, if the pointer is pointing to something you're allowed to modify. For example `char stringer[] = "hello"; char *pointer = stringer; pointer[2] = 'A';` is perfectly valid and fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Some programmer dude in comments:

Literal strings are really non-modifiable arrays of characters. With `char *stringer="hello";` you make `stringer` point to the first character of such an array. Attempting to modify its contents leads to undefined behavior.

That's why you should always use `const char *` when pointing to literal strings.

Strings can be modified when using pointer, if the pointer is pointing to something you're allowed to modify. For example

```
char stringer[] = "hello"; 
char *pointer = stringer; 
pointer[2] = 'A';
```